# VBA need a macro which concatenates top 3 rows of an excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba

I need a macro which will concatenate the top 3 rows of an excel spreadsheet together, then replace the original 3 rows with that new row.

For instance:

```
|      This     |
|is     | an    |
|example|       |
```

would become

```
|This_is_example|This_an|
```

Suggestions?

Comment: example is supposed to look like this
http://s119.photobucket.com/albums/o129/qckslvr688/?action=view&current=picturetoshow.png

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: Is "This" in merged cells? It's not clear (could be "center across selection" for example)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have merged cells:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, rngMerge As Range

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, 100).Cells
        Set rngMerge = c.MergeArea
        If rngMerge.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            c.UnMerge
            rngMerge.Value = rngMerge.Cells(1).Value
        End If
        c.Value = JoinUp(c.Resize(3, 1), "_")
    Next c
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A3").EntireRow.Delete
End Sub


Function JoinUp(rng As Range, Optional Delim As String = "") As String
    Dim c As Range, rv As String
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            rv = rv & IIf(Len(rv) > 0, Delim, "") & c.Value
        End If
    Next c
    JoinUp = rv
End Function
```